# Weight paint and mesh are mirrored, weight paint color seems right, but vertices are left behind

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, mirror

Right now I'm weight painting my mesh, so I can rig it correctly. However, the forearm isn't behaving the way it should, the left one at least. The right one moves the mesh correctly, but the left one leaves a line of vertices behind, even though they are weight painted and the same as the right side. Here's some screenshots:

Weight painted left (uncorrect) side:

[image]

Mesh deforming uncorrectly on the left side:

[image]

Weight painted right (correct) side, it was mirrored from the left one:

[image]

Mesh deforming correctly on the right side:

[image]

Any idea of how I can solve this? I've tried erasing all the painting and doing it again, but the result is the same. The weight of every individual vertex seems to be right. The mesh is mirrored and there's no unnecessary vertices inside it. All fingers and hands worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like it was because I had wrong weight painting in the pelvis bone. Not sure how it ended up painting the right arm, but now it's fixed.